# How to fix "Error : DEP0100 : Deployment failed due to a Developer Licensing issue. Could not obtain a developer license due to error 00000000."

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, hololens-emulator

I am new at hololens emulator in unity.
I am following the youtube video tutorial that present simple capsule object in unity.
Now I meet this issue.
When I create new project on visual studio it works correctly without any errors.
I already turned on developer mode and tried all answers mentioned on this site but not fixed yet.
Please help me.